# Linux - cannot generete core dump

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow, coredump, core-file

I am  doing some buffer overflow tests and i need to generate a core dump, since i dont wont to attach debugger to it because its a multithread application.So what i did is

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

and it looks like evrything went correctly, but when i sent data to create buffer overflow, it should be a core file on desktop but it is not (my application is on desktop)

I also tryed 
`ulimit -c nolimit`

but that didnt work, it throws me invalid number.

I even wrote a new program that is causing segmentation fault but there is no core file.

Iam running Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -c` will change the configuration in the current session only. You will probably need to edit `/etc/profile` and `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

For more info, refer the this page:  [Debugging Linux Cores](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html/)